# How to get Meeting Attendance Report of a Created Teams Online Meeting with Graph Api

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-teams

How to get the attendance report of an online meeting created with Graph Api?

I just want to find duration information who has attended the online meeting.

I can create an online meeting on behalf of a user with using the endpoint `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/....../onlineMeetings` successfully and also get the meeting with using the meeting id.

The response has `meetingAttendanceReport` parameter but it is returning `null`. How to find the information about the attendees?

I have researched the call records api to get these but cannot find the connection between online meeting api and call record api. CallRecord api wants a parameter of `id`.

How to find the call record id of the online meeting?

Answer (score 0):

Please follow example 6 as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/onlinemeeting-get?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http#example-6-retrieve-the-attendance-report-of-a-meeting) to get meeting attendance report of an online meeting.

Please note this is **only available in beta** for now and should not be used with V1 end points.

Also ensure you have necessary permission to call this API.

[image]

Comment: ty for your reply. Do u have any info about the last part of the question?

Comment: There are two ways to get the id of a callRecord:

1- Subscribe to change notifications to the /communications/callRecords endpoint.
2- Use the callChainId property of a call. The call record is available only after the associated call is completed.

Refer documentation here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/callrecords-callrecord-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

Comment: Thanks again for your reply. is there any way to jump call api from the any paramater of an created onlineMeeting?

Comment: Please refrain from asking for upvotes here - we prefer voting to be organic.

Answer (score 0):

This is sample code to get all AttendanceRecords of a meeting with meeting id:

```
var retMeeting = await graphClient.Users[userId].OnlineMeetings.GetAsync((requestConfiguration) =>
 {
     requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Filter = "joinMeetingIdSettings/joinMeetingId eq '354240318240'";
 });

var retReports = await graphClient.Users[userId].OnlineMeetings[retMeeting.Value[0].Id].AttendanceReports.GetAsync();
var log = string.Empty;
log += " Meeting '" + retMeeting.Value[0].Subject + "' (" + retMeeting.Value[0].JoinMeetingIdSettings.JoinMeetingId + 
    "), Planed Time: " + retMeeting.Value[0].StartDateTime.Value.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm") + " - " +
         retMeeting.Value[0].EndDateTime.Value.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm");

for (int j = 0; j < retReports.Value.Count; j++)
{
    var report = retReports.Value[j];
    log += "\n\n  " + (j + 1) + ". Session Time: " + report.MeetingStartDateTime.Value.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm") + " - " +
         report.MeetingEndDateTime.Value.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm") + ", Total Participant : " + report.TotalParticipantCount;

    var retAttendances = await graphClient.Users[userId].OnlineMeetings[retMeeting.Value[0].Id]
        .AttendanceReports[report.Id].AttendanceRecords.GetAsync();

    foreach (var attendance in retAttendances.Value)
    {
        log += "\n\n\tUser: " + attendance.EmailAddress + " (Total Min: " + (attendance.TotalAttendanceInSeconds / 60) + ")";

        for (int i = 0; i < attendance.AttendanceIntervals.Count; i++)
        {
            var interval = attendance.AttendanceIntervals[i];
            log += "\n\t\t" + (i + 1) + ". " + interval.JoinDateTime.Value.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm") + " - " +
                interval.LeaveDateTime.Value.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm") +
                " (Total Min: " + (interval.DurationInSeconds / 60) + ")";
        }
    }
}

Console.WriteLine(log);
```